# Parsing small web page with xml2 throws XML_PARSE_HUGE error

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping, libxml2

Recently a user of my rNOMADS package in R began getting unexpected errors:

```
Error: Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option [1]
```

We tracked the issue down to this command:

```
html.tmp <- xml2::read_html("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_rap.pl?dir=%2Frap.20151120")
```

Upon following the link, it appears that the web page to be parsed is no larger than other ones that work fine, and much less than the 1 megabyte limit that should require the XML_PARSE_HUGE option.  Furthermore,

```
xml2::read_html
```

actually has no XML_PARSE_HUGE option anyway.  The only other potential solution, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419409/set-xml-parse-huge-option-for-xml2xml-text-in-r), is not appropriate for an official R package.

What is the cause of this error, and is it possible to resolve it without resorting to solutions outside the official CRAN repository?

Comment: Yes, I know.  The behavior is really hard to understand.  I use the GFS model all the time, and I've never had this issue.

Comment: `XML_PARSE_HUGE` lifts several limitations. The one you're running into here is the maximum depth of the document tree which is limited to 256 by default. It doesn't take a large document to have more than 256 nested elements.

Comment: @nwellnhof how is this option set? The function read_html does not have it as an input and I am unclear how to change that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do so far is to install [shabbychef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164611/shabbychef)'s forked version of xml2 that forces XML_PARSE_HUGE.  You can install this version of xml2 via

```
library(drat)
drat:::add("shabbychef")
install.packages('xml2')
```

For the time being, please use this work around if you encounter XML_PARSE_HUGE errors in rNOMADS.